# using the variable "file" obtained from `for "file" in` and pass to another script fails

Tags: shell-script, centos, variable, for

I am trying search for all `.mkv` files in my current folder, then using `mediainfo` I want to put the `height` from its meta data to a variable, but it seems it is failing.

This snippet:

```
height=$(mediainfo "input.mkv" | grep -E 'Height'); echo $height; height=${height//[!0-9]/}; echo $height;
```

is working great, it outputs the result I want if I manually insert the file name:

```
# height=$(mediainfo 'input.mkv' | grep -E 'Height'); echo $height; height=${height//[!0-9]/}; echo $height;
Height : 720 pixels
720
```

But, when I try to put it in my `for file in` so that I won't need to manually insert the file name, it keeps failing:

```
for file in *.{mkv}; do height=$(mediainfo "$file" | grep -E 'Height'); echo $height; height=${height//[!0-9]/}; echo $height; done
```

The output of the variable `$height` is empty.

```
# for file in *.{mkv}; do height=$(mediainfo "$file" | grep -E 'Height'); echo $height; height=${height//[!0-9]/}; echo $height; done
(null)
(null)
```

I already tried, changing `"$file"` to `'$file'` and `$file`, but none of them works, am I missing something?

Comment: do you mean `for file in *.mkv`?

Comment: You might be missing a path to your file and you don't need the {} around mkv.

Comment: Even if you're too sleepy to see the error, you should know how to debug.  Experiment with things like  `for file in (whatever); do echo "$file"; mediainfo "$file" | grep -E 'Height'; …` to narrow down the problem.

Comment: BTW, if you use `mediainfo --output="Video;%Height%"` you can remove all that manual parsing code.

Comment: @Scott thanks for the tips, truth is I just started unix this week, so your thoughts are very helpful, will keep that in mind

Comment: I'm surprised that [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) was not triggered by that, but then reading the manual, there's no `,` or `..` in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote `*.{mkv}` instead of `*.mkv`. Therefore the loop will only loop about the one "file" `*.{mkv}` which does not exist. In this case the output of `mediainfo` is simply empty.

Add something like `echo "$file"` in your loop to verify.

Comment: Oh God, I need a sleep.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the '{}' from in the 'for file' part. It should be like this instead:

`for file in *.mkv; do height=$(mediainfo "$file" | grep -E 'Height'); echo $height; height=${height//[!0-9]/}; echo $height; done`

In your code the "*.{mkv}" is expanding to all files ending in '.{mkv}' of which, I presume, there aren't any, so the list in the for statement comes back empty.

Comment: yeah, It used to loop at different format